# Keep background when button is hidden? (CSS/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, css, button, background

I got a form with checkboxes. The Submit button first is hidden. When i check one checkbox at least the button will appear. That is working. But the button has some background image and that will also only appear when the button is visible. I want the background image to be always there. Is there a way to to this?

HTML :

```
  <div class="wrapper2"><input type = button class="next_button"  name="commit"  value="Submit" onClick="resultFunction();" >
```

CSS :

```
.wrapper2{
    margin-top:  230px;
    text-align: center;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(89,106,114,1) 0%, rgba(206,220,231,1) 58%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(89,106,114,1)), color-stop(58%,rgba(206,220,231,1)));
}
```

i forgot to add this here:

```
$(".next_button").hide();

$("#question1, #question2, #question3, #question4").change(function () {
          if ($("#question1").is(':checked') ||
              $("#question2").is(':checked') || 
              $("#question3").is(':checked') || 
              $("#question4").is(':checked') 
           ) {
             $(".next_button").show();

          } 
      });
```

Comment: Can you please share your resultFunction() function?

Comment: it basically just checks if the right checkboxes are checked

Comment: u can add one DIV as container and make background of Div as image  and hide only button.

Comment: yes, i tried that. i forgot to add some code in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to put your button in a container and give the background to this container and make sure the container has width and height and then hiding and showing just the button will keep the container background there.

Comment: but isn't this what i have now?

Comment: so give the container width and height

Answer (score 0):

I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Seteh/q3ykaq8L/) for you, hope it helps.

In short, just toggle the `visibility` rule of your `<input type="submit" ... />` depending on `<input type="checkbox" ... />` state.